# Time Delay for deck cards

Tags: java

I am trying to create a deck game in Java. I want to show four cards, one after another, then wait for a few seconds and display another four cards, and so on. I created the code below, but card number #4 does not show at all. For example, it displays 3 cards then waits for a few seconds, then it displays other 3 cards.

First part of code:

```
class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        int hideCount = 0;
        addFirstCenterLabel();
        addSecondCenterLabel();
        addThirdCenterLabel();
        addForthCenterLabel();
        for (int i = 0 ; i < 32 ; i++) {
            if (button[i] == e.getSource()) {
                if (button[i] == button[0] || button[i] == button[1] ||
                    button[i] == button[2] || button[i] == button[3] ||
                    button[i] == button[4] || button[i] == button[20] ||
                    button[i] == button[21] || button[i] == button[22]) {
                    southPanelbutton.remove(button[i]);
                    southPanelbutton.validate();
                    southPanelbutton.repaint();

                    labelThirdCenter.setIcon(showCard[i]);

                }
            }
            if (button[i] == e.getSource()) {
                if (button[i] == button[5] || button[i] == button[6] ||
                    button[i] == button[7] || button[i] == button[8] ||
                    button[i] == button[9] || button[i] == button[23] ||
                    button[i] == button[24] || button[i] == button[25]) {
                    eastPanelbutton.remove(button[i]);
                    eastPanelbutton.validate();
                    eastPanelbutton.repaint();

                    labelForthCenter.setIcon(showCard[i]);
                }
            }
            if (button[i] == e.getSource()) {
                if (button[i] == button[10] || button[i] == button[11] ||
                    button[i] == button[12] || button[i] == button[13] ||
                    button[i] == button[14] || button[i] == button[26] ||
                    button[i] == button[27] || button[i] == button[28]) {
                    northPanelbutton.remove(button[i]);
                    northPanelbutton.validate();
                    northPanelbutton.repaint();

                    labelSecondCenter.setIcon(showCard[i]);
                }
            }
            if (button[i] == e.getSource()) {
                if (button[i] == button[15] || button[i] == button[16] ||
                    button[i] == button[17] || button[i] == button[18] ||
                    button[i] == button[19] || button[i] == button[29] ||
                    button[i] == button[30] || button[i] == button[31]) {
                    westPanelbutton.remove(button[i]);
                    westPanelbutton.validate();
                    westPanelbutton.repaint();
                    labelFirstCenter.setIcon(showCard[i]);
                    hideCount++;
                }
            }
            if (button[i] == e.getSource()) {
                if (button[i] == button[15] || button[i] == button[16] ||
                    button[i] == button[17] || button[i] == button[18] ||
                    button[i] == button[19] || button[i] == button[29] ||
                    button[i] == button[30] || button[i] == button[31]) {
                    hideCount++;
                    timeDelay();
                    if (hideCount == 1 || hideCount == 2 || hideCount == 3 ||
                        hideCount == 4 || hideCount == 5 || hideCount == 6 ||
                        hideCount == 7 || hideCount == 8) {
                        hideCards();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Second part of code:

```
public void addFirstCenterLabel() {
    // centerPanelLabel.add(labelFirstCenter);
    // centerPanel.add(centerPanelLabel);
    // down table
    centerPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 3;
    centerPanel.add(labelThirdCenter, c);
    add(centerPanel);
}

public void addSecondCenterLabel() {
    // centerPanelLabel.add(labelSecondCenter);
    // centerPanel.add(centerPanelLabel);
    // right table
    c.gridx = 2;
    c.gridy = 1;
    centerPanel.add(labelForthCenter, c);
    add(centerPanel);
}

public void addThirdCenterLabel() {
    // centerPanelLabel.add(labelThirdCenter);
    // centerPanel.add(centerPanelLabel);
    // top label
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 0;
    centerPanel.add(labelSecondCenter, c);
    add(centerPanel);
}

public void addForthCenterLabel() {
    // centerPanelLabel.add(labelForthCenter);
    // centerPanel.add(centerPanelLabel);

    // left table
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 1;
    centerPanel.add(labelFirstCenter, c);
    add(centerPanel);

    // to count the round of the game. each four cards count as 1.
    for (int j = 0 ; j <= 7 ; j++) {
        if (rounds[j] == 0) {
            rounds[j] = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Third part of code:

```
public void hideCards() {
    for (int j = 0 ; j <= 7 ; j++) {
        // System.out.println(rounds[j]);
        // if the round ==1, make the four cards unvisible
        if (rounds[j] == 1) {
            labelThirdCenter.setIcon(emptyCard[0]);
            labelForthCenter.setIcon(emptyCard[0]);
            labelSecondCenter.setIcon(emptyCard[0]);
            labelFirstCenter.setIcon(emptyCard[0]);
        }
    }
}

public void timeDelay() {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(2500); // one second
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Don't know how to handle this", e);
    }
}
```

Comment: You know how to use a debugger, don't you?

Answer (score 0):

Calling `Thread.sleep` on the UI thread is not a good idea. It will disable all UI updates while the thread is sleeping.

I did not check in detail but it seems that the drawing of card 4 is scheduled, but not yet executed when the thread goes to sleep.